# Are qubits preferred over qumode, and if so, why?

Tags: experimental-realization, continuous-variable

Qubit and qumode are different forms of quantum computation. But most existing quantum computers/chips seems to be of discrete variables. I heard that a group chose qubit for a quantum optical frequency comb experiment relating to quantum computing because the environment noise of continuous variable is much higher. Is this a reason for preferring qubit to qumode at present (if people do prefer it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both models have their potential advantages and disadvantages. The CV model doesn't require energy intensive cooling systems. CV will also work better for continuous-valued problems. Nevertheless, since the model uses photons it brings various challenges to the table as well. Since both models (especially CV)  aren't developed, your question may not be the right one to ask right now.

If you're interested, I know that Xanadu is developing the CV model. They have some papers on CV algorithms and QML out right now.

Comment: Thanks, actually I have been studying things about the CV quantum computation for several years (as a beginner). But recently I have heard some pessimistic views about CV quantum computing, especially those implemented on optical devices. That's why I asked the question ^_^||| Xanadu's work is very interesting. Thanks for your introduction.